# Convertir dd-mm-YYYY HH::mm:ss a date en javascript

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo hacer la conversión de una fecha en string *dd-mm-YYYY HH::mm:ss* al date de javascript e inversamente la conversión del date de javascript a una fecha string.

Hasta el momento tengo esto funcionando:

```
fech = $("#fechaHoraInicioAgenda").val().split("-");
var fecha = new Date(fech[2], fech[1] - 1, fech[0]);
```

No se que tan posible sea realizar la conversión teniendo el formato de fecha y hora.

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Edite la pregunta, revisala nuevamente.

Comment: `new Date(year,month,day,hour,min,sec)`
por ejemplo:

`x=new Date(2017,02,01,08,01,01)`

Wed Mar 01 2017 08:01:01 GMT-0600

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez ponlo como respuesta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con Javascript puro podrías realizar lo siguiente para convertir la fecha a Date y convertirla nuevamente al mismo formato como un string.

```
var initialDate = "24-04-2016 04:24:00"

//Dividimos la fecha primero utilizando el espacio para obtener solo la fecha y el tiempo por separado
var splitDate= initialDate.split(" ");
var date=splitDate[0].split("-");
var time=splitDate[1].split(":");

// Obtenemos los campos individuales para todas las partes de la fecha
var dd=date[0];
var mm=date[1]-1;
var yyyy =date[2];
var hh=time[0];
var min=time[1];
var ss=time[2];

// Creamos la fecha con Javascript
var fecha = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd,hh,min,ss);

// De esta manera se puede volver a convertir a un string
var formattedDate = ("0" + fecha.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (fecha.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + fecha.getFullYear() + ' ' + ("0" + fecha.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + fecha.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + fecha.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

Pero creo que sería recomendable que revisaras la libreria moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) pues facilita bastante trabajar con fechas y sus formatos en Javascript.

Comment: Un pequeño detalle, que al mismo OP se le pasó, el separador entre horas y minutos en la pregunta es doble `:` :)